# How to email a report pdf from JaserReports/iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

We are using JasperReports and IReport.  Reports are created and running great on the server.

However, we would like to be able to email the reports out to the email address stored in the db, instead of printing and mailing.

Any help in getting started with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generate the report and save to the any folder inside your app server ( or in the machine where this is running, in case this is a desktop app).

Then using Java Mail API you can mail the report.

Comment: Could you explain little bit more how can i use Java Mail API because i never worked on Java?